# Why am I getting an unpermitted parameters error in Rails using a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a little problem here where I am trying to make a form with nested attributes and I keep on getting an unpermitted parameters error. This is the code in the `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics

    has_many :subjects, through: :topics
end
```

This is the code in the `subject.rb` file:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics
    has_many :users, through: :topics, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :topics, reject_if: :all_blank, update_only: true,allow_destroy: true
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

This is the code in the `topic.rb` file:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

This is the code in my `subjects_controller.rb`:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login

    def new
        @subject = current_user.subjects.build
        @subject.topics.build
    end

    def create
        @subject = current_user.subjects.build(subject_params)
        if @subject.save
            flash[:success] = "New subject created!"
            redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Errors!!!"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def subject_params
        params.require(:subject).permit(:name, topics_attributes: [:name,:user_id,:subject_id])
    end

end
```

This is my code in the view that creates the form:

```
<%= form_for @subject do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Subject" %><br>
    <%= collection_select :user, :subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :topic do |t| %>

        <%= t.label :name, "Topic" %>
        <%= t.text_field :name %>

    <% end %>

    <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit class: "button radius" %></div>

<% end %>
```

This is my `topics_controller.rb`:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login
    before_action :find_subject

    def new
        @topic = @subject.topics.build
    end

    def create
        @topic = @subject.topics.build(topic_params)
        @topic.user_id = current_user.id
        if @topic.save
            flash[:success] = "Success!"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Error!"
        end
    end

    private
    def topic_params
        params.require(:topic).permit(:name,:subject_id,:user_id)
    end

    def find_subject
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
    end
end
```

I am thinking the reason why I am getting an `Unpermitted parameters: topic` error is because I'm not passing in the "user_id" or "subject_id" upon submission of the form.  If this is the case how would I do this with a hidden form field?  Or does anyone have any other suggestions as to where I may be going wrong?

This is the server log for what's currently happening:

```
Processing by SubjectsController#create as HTML
Processing by SubjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o42ESf7kQ4R3pB6CUvcEetmqoZOmIK8V4UrVTQ5BW/M=", "user"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"}, "subject"=>{"topics_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"something"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Subject"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"o42ESf7kQ4R3pB6CUvcEetmqoZOmIK8V4UrVTQ5BW/M=", "user"=>{"subject_id"=>"1"}, "subject"=>{"topics_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"something"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Subject"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `fields_for` in view as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for :topics do |t| %>

    <%= t.label :name, "Topic" %>
    <%= t.text_field :name %>

<% end %>
```

As you have a `One to Many` relationship setup between `Subject` and `Topic`, you must use plural `topics` as `fields_for` argument.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the advice on that, and now I'm not longer getting that "Unpermitted parameters" error, but now the data entered into the "Topic" field actually isn't being saved into the database.  I'm thinking I have to grab the "user_id" and "subject_id" before saving it into my database.  Could you take a quick look at my topics_controller.rb to see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Please accept this answer as it resolves the Original Question regarding `Unpermitted parameters`. On the comment question, check the params hash generated in server log upon submitting form, see if `user_id ` and `subject_id` are being passed as part of `topic_attributes`

Comment: It's best to avoid setting id's directly.  It means you aren't using rails helpers and once you start doing it some parts of the framework won't work if you "fall off the rails".  See my answer for a suggestion and also consider accepting this answer from Kirti and posting your question as another SO question.

Comment: Glad to help :) Please accept the answer when you get time. Also, as suggested by Michael Durrant post another question for the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Subject` from

```
has_many :subjects, through: :topics, dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
has_many :users, through: :topics
```